# How to enable remote debugging of Stored Procs with MSSQL Linux Docker container?

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker

I'm running the latest [SQL Server docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/tags) from DockerHub in a Linux environment.  Port 1433 is forwarded from my container, and everything is working fine.

However, when I have tried to connect via SSMS to do remote debugging of a Stored Procedure, I see that the Debug->Start Debugging greyed out in SSMS.  From what I understand, Debugging needs port 135 to be open/enabled in the container mapping as well.

So I changed my container startup script to be the following:

```
create --name mssql2 -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=P@$$12345'  -p 135:135  -p 1433:1433  -v /home/eric/docker/mssql:/var/opt/mssql -v /usr/share/zoneinfo:/usr/share/zoneinfo:ro -e TZ=America/Toronto microsoft\
/mssql-server-linux

docker start mssql2
```

However, when I try to telnet to port 135, however, the connection is immediately closed:

```
eric@localhost ~/docker $ telnet localhost 135
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

If I login into the mssql2 container and running netstat (after installing the net-tools package) I see:

```
root@2a378b0479d9:/etc# netstat -ano
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       Timer
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1433            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1434          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.3:57064        91.189.88.162:80        TIME_WAIT   timewait (7.52/0/0)
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.3:36154        91.189.88.149:80        TIME_WAIT   timewait (54.62/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37135         127.0.0.1:1433          ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40978         127.0.0.1:1433          TIME_WAIT   timewait (18.04/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1433          127.0.0.1:45665         ESTABLISHED keepalive (7051.49/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1433          127.0.0.1:37135         ESTABLISHED keepalive (7051.46/0/0)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45665         127.0.0.1:1433          ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
```

So clearly MSSQL isn't even listening on port 135 within the container. What do I need to do to enable the remote debug port on the docker container? I do not even see any reference to port 135 in the logfile either.  Is there a special switch I need to use in the MSSQL configuration to tell it to enable remote debugging?

Comment: I am looking to do the exact same thing. I am curious if you have tried Kubernetes or not? Is this a linux container issue, or a docker issue? I believe it would be MSSQL on linux issue, but I am just being curious.